# How can I monitor the SQL my Delphi application executes?

Tags: sql, delphi, monitoring, delphi-xe

Is there a way in Delphi XE to have an SQL monitor that tracks all SQL done by my application? Delphi 5 had a component for it.

Comment: SQL Monitor works with BDE, are you still using BDE or another components?

Comment: @RRUZ - [TSQLMonitor](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SqlExpr_TSQLMonitor.html) is part of dbexpress.

Comment: @Sertac, I think Which the OP is talking about the `Sql Monitor` tool, which is part of the Delphi IDE 5.

Comment: @RRUZ - Sorry, I didn't know about that one. Hope OP posts a little bit of more detail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question can only be answered "maybe" the way you've asked it. You don't mention which database engine you're using or which data access controls, which are essential to the question. Please edit your question and provide more information (like the DB engine being used, which components you're using to access that DBMS, and what component you're referencing that you used in Delphi 5). Thanks. :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you use components that support multiple dbmses, the solution need not be dbms specific.

Comment: @Sam If not DBMS specific, at least component-specific. For instance, we offer [auto SQL logging for the DB access layer of our ORM](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/07/SQLite3-powered%2C-not-SQLite3-limited). Will work for all DBMS, because SQL logging is made in the abstract layer. But AFAIK there is no "generic" solution in Delphi. Even the Delphi 5 solution was BDE-specific.

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez - I think you are basically agreeing with me. If you use ZeosLib or dbExpress, the SQLs can be captured and logged in the same way in the same place without caring about the DBMS actually being accessed. Even minor variations in SQL syntax for different DBMS doesn't mean you need a different solution for the different DBMS types. My only point is that the solution does not need to depend on the type of DBMS as the above comments seem to imply. I think we are in sync but slightly out of phase.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067390/how-can-i-monitor-the-sql-commands-send-over-my-ado-connection) you might use TAdoConnection.OnWillExecute event to send queries to the console, eg:

```
procedure TDataModuleProd.ADOConnection1WillExecute(
  Connection: TADOConnection; var CommandText: WideString;
  var CursorType: TCursorType; var LockType: TADOLockType;
  var CommandType: TCommandType; var ExecuteOptions: TExecuteOptions;
  var EventStatus: TEventStatus; const Command: _Command;
  const Recordset: _Recordset);
begin
  {$ifdef DEBUG}
     OutputDebugString(PChar('SQL Execute: ' + CommandText));
  {$endif}
end;
```

Comment: Sorry... Where in the question do you see ADO mentioned? I must have missed it somewhere. :)

Comment: ... and you'll loose bound parameters values with this... not so relevant information... need at least to retrieve them and add them to the logged text.

Comment: Thanks, and how display the console in Delphi XE so ,

Answer (score 0):

If you use devart unidac components for database operations, they have perfect tool for that: https://www.devart.com/dbmonitor/
Other option would be to write wrappers for SQL components you are using and write all info into log file your self.