# Why does this code return 0 records in delphi 10 using sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I am trying to use a combobox to select records in an app for myself using delphi 10.4

```
if cbResultDisplaySelect.ItemIndex = 1 then
begin
  d1  :=  DateTimePicker1.Date;
  d2  :=  DateTimePicker2.Date;
  mmdata.labRstQry.Active := false;
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Clear;
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Add('select * from labs ');
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Add('where ldate Between ' + DateToStr(d1) + ' and ' + DatetoStr(d2));
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Add(' group by ldate, ltestname order by ltestname, ldate DESC');
  mmdata.labRstQry.Active := true;
end else...
```

It keeps returning an empty result.

If I write this in the sql editor in SqliteStudio it works:

```
select * from labs where ldate BETWEEN '2022-09-01' and '2022-12-31';
```

I have tried formatting the date from the datetimepicker to 'yyyy-MM-dd' and it did not work either.  It must be something very basic I'm doing wrong or missing

Comment: As part of debugging look at what query is actually being sent to SQLite3. Can be done as easily as dropping a TMemo on the form and doing `Memo1.lines := mmdata.labRstQry.SQL;` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In queries you should use FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd', d1). DateToStr(d1) is locale dependant and you can't predict how it will format your date.
And your dates need to be QuotedStr.

So in the end: QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd', d1))

Your code would make something like:

```
select * from labs where ldate BETWEEN 09/01/2022 and 12/31/2022
```

If you use QuotedStr and FormatDateTime you get

```
select * from labs where ldate BETWEEN '20220901' and '20221231'
```

You're better off learning how to write queries with parameters.
I haven't tested it but your code would look something like this:

```
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Add('select * from labs ');
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Add('where ldate Between :begindate and :enddate';
  mmdata.labRstQry.SQL.Add(' group by ldate, ltestname order by ltestname, ldate DESC');
  mmdata.labRstQry.ParamByName('begindate').Value := d1;
  mmdata.labRstQry.ParamByName('enddate').Value := d2;
  mmdata.labRstQry.Active := true;
```

Parameters can sometimes be a little finicky, like don't use the same parameter twice in one query.

Comment: So why don't you add an example using parameters since you already mention it!?

Comment: By using parameters no need to mess with quotes. You can find out how below:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989265/how-to-pass-string-parameters-to-an-tadoquery

Comment: @DelphiCoder like that? Normalllly I just answer just the question. The comment about parameters was just a nudge in the rigt direction.

Comment: yes, thanks for adding the parameters example

Comment: it would be best to wrap d1 and d2 in Dateof()