# TFDQuery and TADOQuery with identical syntax

Tags: delphi, ado, firedac

I want to extend the class  TMyQuery with the  property parameters.
I want to call  TMyQuery  with the same syntax as  using a TADOQuery.
How to  extend  my Class correctly ?

```
///  new class    
type TMyQuery = class (TFDQuery)
      private
    
        procedure SetParamByName(const Param: TParam);
       public
       ///  here i fail ! 
       property Parameters[const AName: string]: TParam  Write SetParamByName;
    end;
    
procedure TMyQuery.SetParamByName(const Param: TParam);
begin
   // Params.ParamByName(AName). ???  ;
end;    
///  code example    
...
...
///  calling FFDQuery with same syntax like ADO Query     
qryInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := recordCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try some like this:

```
  TMyQuery = class (TFDQuery)
  private
    procedure SetParamByName(const AName: string; const Value: TParam);
  public
    /// ...
    property Parameters[const AName: string]: TParam  Write SetParamByName;
  end;
```

On implementation of the procedure try this:

```
procedure TMyQuery.SetParamByName(const AName: string; const Value: TParam);
begin
  inherited ParamByName(AName).Value := Value.Value;
end;
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: [dcc64 Error] Unit_Test.pas(307): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'AsInteger' ,  why did he forget .AsInteger

Comment: not sure  how to imitate TADO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989265/how-to-pass-string-parameters-to-an-tadoquery         .Value property  with my approach