# TADOConnection.OnExecuteComplete / OnWillExecute event not called with TADOTable

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe7

I try to trace SQL command. I read this post : [How can I monitor the SQL commands send over my ADO connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067390/how-can-i-monitor-the-sql-commands-send-over-my-ado-connection)

It does work for select but not for Delete/Insert/Update...

Configuration : A `TADOConnection` (MS SQL Server), a `TADOTable`, a `TDatasource`, a `TDBGrid` with `TDBNavigator`.

So I can trace the `SELECT` which occurs when the table is open, but nothing occurs when I use the DBNavigator to `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` records.

When I use a TADOCommand to delete a record, it works too. It seems It doesn't work only when I use the DBNavigator so maybe a clue but I don't find anything about that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that I'm using Delphi XE7

Comment: Put that in your question text (and you can add the appropriate tag as well)

Comment: I need to trace Sql programmatically, inside the application, not from Sql server because I need somme informations the server has not. That's the constraint...

Comment: @ MartynA : Maybe the q title is enough ?

Comment: The application use DbGrid/DbNav to display, update, insert, delete records. To display records,you make this : ADOC.ConnectionString := GetConnString();
TB_EMC2LAB.Active:=True;
The OnExecuteComplete works. I see the SELECT command in the log. Then if I try to udate the record, in the form, I type some text then click on update bitton. Nothing happens. The record is updated. But no log with 'UPDATE etc.'

Comment: @martynA, it is really simple, no code is needed. The TADOTable will load an internal ADO recordset object by firing the select at load and then it will use the recordset object for CRUD statements, bypassing the TADOConnection.

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  Thanks, that explains why the events don't fire when using the DBNav, but I'm still puzzled exactly what the OP is saying *does* work ...

Comment: @MartynA, It does work when your replace TADOTable with TADOCommand, because TADOCommand will always use the ADOConnection instead of an internal recordset.

Comment: @whosrdaddy : Is there any way to make the event fire ? I can't figure out how DBNav "bypass" ADOConnection ... What does it mean ? ADOConnection is the only way known to the app to communicate with database.

Comment: It seems that operations on a recordset are not captured by these events.

Comment: So ? Absolutely no way to log an update ?

Comment: " how DBNav "bypass" ADOConnection ".  It's not the dBNav which does the bypassing.  When you open the AdoTable, it instantiates an ADO recordset object (in the MDAC layer), which has its own access to the ADO connection object (also in the MDAC layer) which connects to the server as the AdoConnection in your app does.  So, it's the recordset which "bypasses" the AdoConnection, not the DBNav.

Comment: @ MartynA : Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone will be able to point you in the direction of a pre-existing library that does your logging for you.  In particular, if FireDAC is an option, you might take a look at what it says in here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29

Of course, converting your app from using Ado to FireDAC, may not be an option for you, but depending on how great your need is, you could conceivably extract the Sql-Server-specific method of event alerting FireDAC uses into an Ado application.  I looked into this briefly a while ago and it looked like it would be fairly straightforward.

Prior to FireDAC, I implemented a server-side solution that caught Inserts, Updates and Deletes.  I had to do this about 10 years ago (for Sql Server 2000) and it was quite a performance to set up.

In outline it worked like this:

Sql Server supports what MS used to call "extended stored procedures" which are implemented in custom DLLs (MS may refer to them by a different name these days or have even stopped supporting them).  There are Delphi libraries around that provide a wrapper to enable these to be written in Delphi.  Of course, these days, if your Sql Server is 64-bit, you need to generate a 64-bit DLL.

You write Extended Stored Procedures to log the changes any way you want, then write custom triggers in the database for Inserts, Updates and Deletes, that feed the data of the rows involved to your XSPs.

As luck would have it, my need for this fell away just as I was completing the project, before I got to stress-testing and performance-profiling it but it did work.

Of course, not in every environment will you be allowed/able to install s/ware and trigger code on the Sql Server.

For interest, you might also take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162565.aspx, which provides an SMO object for tracing Sql Server activity, though it seems to be 32-bit only at the moment.

For amusement, I might have a go at implementing an event-handler for the recordset object that underlies a TAdoTable/TAdoQuery, which sould be able to catch the changes you're after but don't hold your breath ...

And, of course, if you're only interested in client-side logging, one way to do it is to write handlers for your dataset's AfterEdit, AfterInsert and AfterDelete events.  Those wouldn't guarantee that the changes are ever actually applied at the server, of course, but could provide an accurate record of the user's activity, if that's sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your knowledge and your time. FireDac doesn't seems to be an option for me, and I have no access to the server. So.., indeed, I'm writing this kind of code : AfterEdit, AfterInsert, BeforeDelete and so on at Dataset level. And what It could be written in two hours in an elegant manner with the ADO will now takes two days and so many lines of dirty code. But no choice. I'll work this night :-(. However, I find it's a lack in Delphi to not be able to use ADO in any circumstances, DataSet or not. Regards.